# Command not found: psql

Tags: macos, psql, postgresapp

After following the installation guide here: https://postgresapp.com/, I ran the command in step 3 to configure my path and was presented with this:

`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

However, after then typing `which psql` I get `psql not found`, and when trying to start my local database get `command not found: psql`.

I am able to start up the PostgreSQL app and initialize, but can't seem to run any commands in the terminal associated with psql.

Comment: which OS you have?

Comment: macOS Big Sur 11.4